# missing $GOPATH when I building omaha

Tags: python-2.7

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8NpjB.png)

Please see the image, I am building my project on widows 10

Comment: What does this have to do with Python 2.7?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by installing Go 1.14.2. Its recommended here in this github issue: https://github.com/google/omaha/issues/295